# Using Dwoo 2.0 in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, dwoo

### Heading

Hey,
I would like to use the new Dwoo 2.0 Template Engine in my CakePHP app. But I can't find any manual with a step by step instruction. I know it's just in a beta status but it would be great if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to follow up on
https://github.com/ganglia/ganglia-web/tree/master/dwoo/Dwoo/Adapters/CakePHP

and make this some clean "Dwoo" Plugin with a DwooView class you can then switch out via

```
$this->viewClass = 'Dwoo.Dwoo';
```

See https://github.com/predominant/TwigView as an example how its done properly (in this case for Twig, though).

Don't forget some test cases and a good documentation and I bet in no time lots of other people will join in and also use and enhance your view class.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use Dwoo 2 with CakePHP framework, it's possible to ork with you to update the Dwoo 1 Adapter to the version 2 of Dwoo.

Let me know!

best regards